# How to resolve Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionContext.GetNormalizedRouteValue in .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

## Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionContext.GetNormalizedRouteValue() doesn't exist

I am implementing a custom Razor ViewEngine in .net Core 2.2.

MSDN states that the `GetNormalizedRouteValue()` method exists within Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal for .Net Core 2.2, but it looks like it doesn't exist when I compile or inspect the assembly.

### My Code

My code context where I am using use it is `context.GetNormalizedRouteValue(AREA_KEY)`

```
public class CustomViewEngine : IViewEngine
{
 public ViewEngineResult FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
        {
            var controllerName = context.GetNormalizedRouteValue(CONTROLLER_KEY);
            var areaName = context.GetNormalizedRouteValue(AREA_KEY);

            var checkedLocations = new List<string>();
            foreach (var location in _options.ViewLocationFormats)
            {
                var view = string.Format(location, viewName, controllerName);
                if (File.Exists(view))
                {
                    return ViewEngineResult.Found("Default", new CustomView(view, _customViewRendering));
                }
                checkedLocations.Add(view);
            }

            return ViewEngineResult.NotFound(viewName, checkedLocations);
        }
```

### Microsoft's API

When inspecting the Microsoft API, only the following method signatures appear to exist.

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
{

    public class ActionContext
    {

        public ActionContext();

        public ActionContext(ActionContext actionContext);

        public ActionContext(HttpContext httpContext, RouteData routeData, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor);

        public ActionContext(HttpContext httpContext, RouteData routeData, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, ModelStateDictionary modelState);

        public ActionDescriptor ActionDescriptor { get; set; }

        public HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; }

        public ModelStateDictionary ModelState { get; }

        public RouteData RouteData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've checked [MSDN's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.internal.normalizedroutevalue.getnormalizedroutevalue?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and it indicates it should exist.

### Error

> 'ActionContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetNormalizedRouteValue'  and no accessible extension method 'GetNormalizedRouteValue' accepting a  first argument of type 'ActionContext' could be found (are you missing a  using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetNormalizedRouteValue()` method is `static` and is defined on the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.NormalizedRouteValue` type.

Try this instead:

```
var controllerName = NormalizedRouteValue.GetNormalizedRouteValue(context, CONTROLLER_KEY);
```

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.internal.normalizedroutevalue.getnormalizedroutevalue?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Internal_NormalizedRouteValue_GetNormalizedRouteValue_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_System_String_)

Comment: Isn't it [internal](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/NormalizedRouteValue.cs) by chance?

Comment: @WiktorZychla, I actually referred to the one defined on a different namespace that the one you pointed to. See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.1/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/NormalizedRouteValue.cs#L23 - The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.NormalizedRouteValue` type and its `GetNormalizedRouteValue` method are both `public` (for v2.2, as used by OP)

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to do some changes in your code 
Make sure you are using

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
```

GetNormalizedRouteValue method is now public. So you can call RazorViewEngine.GetNormalizedRouteValue method

Replace following line

```
 var controllerName = context.GetNormalizedRouteValue(CONTROLLER_KEY);
```

Your method will be like this

```
 public ViewEngineResult FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
  {
   var controllerName = RazorViewEngine.GetNormalizedRouteValue(context, CONTROLLER_KEY);
   var areaName = RazorViewEngine.GetNormalizedRouteValue(context, AREA_KEY)             
                //your code
    }
```

Mircosoft API

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
{

    public class RazorViewEngine : IRazorViewEngine, IViewEngine
    {
        public static readonly string ViewExtension;
        protected IMemoryCache ViewLookupCache { get; }
        public static string GetNormalizedRouteValue(ActionContext context, string key);
        public RazorPageResult FindPage(ActionContext context, string pageName);
        public ViewEngineResult FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage);
        public string GetAbsolutePath(string executingFilePath, string pagePath);
        public RazorPageResult GetPage(string executingFilePath, string pagePath);
        public ViewEngineResult GetView(string executingFilePath, string viewPath, bool isMainPage);
    }
}
```